# How to extract decode JSON from REDCap Array with PHP

Tags: php, json, redcap

I have an JSON Export from a REDCap and it started as a nested ARRAY. I use json_decode, but when I print the result I get an ERROR.

Here is the Array:

```
[{"record_id":"13","lastname":"Mustermann","first_name":"Json","dob":"1948-10-12","case_number":"1366613"}]
```

My Code is:

```
$deco = json_decode($json);
print $deco;
```

The line "echo" gives an error. What am I doing wrong?!
Thank you

Comment: https://3v4l.org/AShp0

Comment: Thank you @nick, but I want to assign different values to a variables like $rec => 13 and this gives an error also. How can I correct it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php

Comment: I already did, döst work for me

Comment: https://3v4l.org/sEJPY

Comment: The array start as nested one and there is no name before it to call (no “toppings” like in the question you send me). I try the solutions there, but I get only errors

Comment: See the updated demo code I posted in my last comment

Comment: @Nick thank! It works.